# get hash via url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have to reset a password from a hash generated by bcrypt...

```
hash = $2a$11$Ro/Y5GnkI6v1DkewwZAcBeZY7Q2a9872NUGDuXXes4J5SWfEQGHvG
```

the problem is that hash have an slash... so in my router

```
app.get('/getHash/:hash',routes.getResetHash);
```

i get an 404 error! i think the problem is the slash between $Ro and Y5G in the hash
because the hash try to search an url like this

```
app.get('/getHash/$2a$11$Ro/Y5GnkI6v1DkewwZAcBeZY7Q2a9872NUGDuXXes4J5SWfEQGHvG'.....
```

how can i stringify the hash... ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to URL escape the hash. Javascript has two functions for this `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`... you want the latter since you only want to encode a single part of it including the slashes:

```
uri_safe_hash = encodeURIComponent(hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to URI-escape special characters like `/`, `&`, and `?`. In this case, your hash would be wrapped like so:

```
var hash = encodeURIComponent('$2a$11$Ro/Y...872NUGDuXXes4J5SWfEQGHvG');
```

On the server side, it should automatically re-convert the escaped parameters, but you will need to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
app.get('/getHash/:hash1/:hash2', routes.getResetHash);
```

Then on routes.getResetHash you can join the hash1 and hash2 parameters:

```
routes.getResetHash = function(req, res){
  var hash = req.params.hash1 + '/' + req.params.hash2;
});
```